# Stokes' Theorem question

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

This is the question I wanna ask

[image]

The question 2 in http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_spring_09/PDF/13-07-Stokes-thm.pdf  is similar to the question I asked, but I still have no idea how to do the question.

For (i)  I tried to convert the equation into $r(t)$ format.

The vector field $(F) = (y,z,x)$ from the question

Let's say $C1$ is the line from $(3,0,0)$ to $(0,4,0)$

so $r(t)=(3-3t, 4t, 0)$

$r'(t)= (-3,4,0)dt$

then after integrating $C1,C2$ and $C3,$ I added them together, the answer is $-23.5.$

In (ii), I got $-18$

there must be something wrong because i and ii should give the same answer.

Comment: What did you get for the curl of the vector field?

Comment: (-1,-1,-1).........

Comment: anyone? .......